Why is the standard wave equation for the propagation of waves
I was studying the derivation for the formula of the speed of light:
$$c = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu_0 \varepsilon_0}}
$$
I used chatGPT, [I suspect it's wrong] to show me the derivation using Maxwell's laws of electromagnetism, I understood all steps of it until the final step for the derivation.
It told me this :  Ampere's law with Maxwell's correction
$$\nabla \times \mathbf{B} = \mu_0 \left( \mathbf{J} + \varepsilon_0 \frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t} \right)$$
And as $\mathbf{J}$ is $0$, the law simplifies to :
$$\nabla \times \mathbf{B} = \mu_0 \varepsilon_0 \frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t}
$$
Now , using faraday's law,
$$\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = -\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t}
$$
and taking the curl of it,
$$
\nabla \times (\nabla \times \mathbf{E}) = -\nabla \times \frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t}
$$
Now using the identity:
$$\nabla \times (\nabla \times \mathbf{E}) = -\nabla^2 \mathbf{E}
$$ ($\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E} = 0$ as a consequence of simplified Gauss' law in case of vacuum)
So now after a lot of simplification,
It simplifies to,
$$\nabla^2 \mathbf{E} = \mu_0 \varepsilon_0 \frac{\partial^2 \mathbf{E}}{\partial t^2}
$$
Now is the part where I can't understand the logic
chatGPT cites a so-called wave equation for an electromagnetic wave which is :
$$\nabla^2 \psi = \frac{1}{v^2} \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial t^2}
$$
And then it equates our derivation equation and the so called , standard wave equation and then $v$ gets solved.
I couldn't find any form of this "standard wave equation" anywhere on the internet, can someone please explain me this equation and how was it derived??
[ I am a ninth grader , and all of this stuff is self learnt so my knowledge may be incomplete in some areas ]

Here is a classic derivation of the wave equation from a string under tension with small displacements. This is the way I was first exposed to it. Wikipedia also has lots of information about the wave equation.

If you want to get some idea of why it's called the wave equation, try plugging $\psi=A \cos(\omega t - k x)$ into the wave equation. You should find this is a solution if $\omega = k v$, which is an example of a dispersion relationship, and from there you can see that $v$ is the group velocity. Then it's worth staring at $\cos(\omega t - k x)$, and plotting it as a function of $x$ for different values of $t$ (with fixed $\omega, v,$ and $k=\omega/v$), to see that it is a traveling wave.

Your question title isn't even a full sentence, what was it supposed to say?

You are correct to suspect that ChatGPT answers are bad, but this is one of the super rare cases in which it is correct.

A student’s first intro to the wave equation is usually in the mechanics of a vibrating string (as in music, not as in string theory). The case of electromagnetic waves normally comes later, after simpler kinds of waves are well-understood.

You're free to write any mathematical equation you like, as long as it contains no mistakes. One of these infinite number of equation you can write is what we call the "wave equation", namely
$$\frac{1}{v^2} \partial_{tt} u(\mathbf{r},t) - \nabla^2 u(\mathbf{r},t) = f(\mathbf{r},t) \ ,$$
for which some theoretical, analytical and numerical results are well known, qualitatively summarized as "the field $u(\mathbf{r},t)$ propagates in space and time as a wave", whatever a wave is: usually, something that reminds you of sea waves, or waves in strings of some instruments,... that - surprise! - are solutions of wave equations resulting from mathematical manipulation of physical principles and governing equations in fluid mechanics and structural mechanics.
Among the infinite number of equations you can write, some of them appears quite often in several different fields, like wave equation or diffusion equation. So:

it's worth to study the solution of these equations in depth
you can derive the same equation performing algebraic and calculus manipulation of governing equations in different fields. Just to name few examples for the wave equation:

electromagnetic field in free space: starting from Maxwell's equations as physical principles, and adding the assumption of no charges
small perturbation of pressure in compressible flows at rest: starting from mass, momentum, energy equations - and using thermodynamics - and adding the small-perturbation assumption
axial vibrations of elastic beams: using momentum dynamical equilibrium equation in the axial direction



If there is no volume forcing, $f(\mathbf{r},t) = 0$. The unknown function $u(\mathbf{r},t)$ can be a scalar, vector or tensor function.
My thoughts. Maybe it's too early for a 9-th grader to deal with electromagnetism and vector calculus

Well , schwinger used to read dirac's papers in high school, so I agree to disagree with your last statement.
